# EJS pass text into partial

Tags: javascript, html, render, ejs

I'm struggling to pass some text into my child component via the parent. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do this?

Here's my parent:

```
<% include ../partials/hero %>
```

Heres my child:

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 g-no-padding">
        <div class="cont">
          <img class="hero--img" src="../img/hero.jpg">
          <h1 class="hero--title g-title--big g-font--white">TEXT PASSED FROM PARENT</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using:

```
<% var data= 'blah blah blah'; %>
```

...and tried calling using :

```
<%= data %>
```

...but it only threw errors for me. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [EJS documentation](https://github.com/mde/ejs#layouts):

> EJS does not specifically support blocks, but layouts can be implemented by including headers and footers, like so:

```
<%- include('header') -%>
<h1>
    Title
</h1>
<p>
    My page
</p>
<%- include('footer') -%>
```

TL;DR You cannot pass content to includes in EJS